# xPath to extract values from a specific table?

Tags: web-scraping, xpath, extract

Some time ago I successfully made a database with number of cars sold in specific countries. The website I extracted data from has changed and data for multiple countries is now mixed on same page. Example:

Using xPath **//tr[td='2020']/td[2]** picks 2 values (Europe and China) in
https://www.goodcarbadcar.net/skoda-octavia-sales-figure/ and https://www.goodcarbadcar.net/skoda-superb-sales-figure/

And 5 values (US, Canada, Europe, China) in
https://www.goodcarbadcar.net/bmw-3-series-sales-figures/

Is there any solution to extract sales figures separately for each country? The expected output must have one row for each model and one column for each year/country (US 1990-2023 sales, Canada 1990-2023 sales, Europe 1990-2023 sales, China 1990-2023 sales). Note that title above tables are not consistent, for BMW 3-Series and Skoda Octavia is "Europe Annual Sales" while for Skoda Superb is "Yearly".

Comment: you can extract the country name first, and get the static tables as an iterator, then get the iterator index to match the country name.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can pick a specific value if you know how many values there are. For example, to pick the second value (in either page you linked) you can use:

```
(//div[contains(@class,"dataTables_wrapper")])[2]//td[.="2020"]/following-sibling::td
```

which will give you the 2020 China Annual Sales.

You can figure out how many values there are by using

```
count(//div[contains(@class,"dataTables_wrapper")])
```

Comment: Does not pick right data when number of tables vary from page to page

Comment: @Future - Not sure I understand; can you edit your question and show the exact expected output from these 2 links?

Comment: I don't know what was not clear "Is there any solution to extract sales figures separately for each country?" The expected output must have one row for each model and one column for each year/country (US 1990-2023 sales, Canada 1990-2023 sales, Europe 1990-2023 sales, China 1990-2023 sales).

Comment: @Future - First, which version of xpath are you using? Second, are you using xpath in a python environment, in a browser console tab, standalone (such as in BaseX), etc.?

Comment: Standalone C# application using HtmlAgilityPack

Comment: @Future - I see; I'm afraid I'm not that familiar with HtmlAgilityPack. See if you can set up a sandbox with it ([here, for example](https://html-agility-pack.net/online-examples)) and I'll try to play with it.

Comment: As far I know xPath is an universal language regardles of environment used, if you want to know, the scraper is written in C# using HtmlAgilityPack, I also use XPath Helper extension for Chrome to click various elements of page and figure out which xPath to use in my scraper, but it does not help in current case.

Comment: @Future Xpath is indeed universal but it comes in a few versions, from 1.0 to 3.1. Unfortunately,  HtmlAgilityPack only supports xpath 1.0. Also, your specific issue requires using a loop which requires either xquery (which, AFAIK, is also not supported) or native c# functions.